# Github Actions "...failed: No such file or directory (2) rsync error: error in file IO (code 11)" on automatic deploy jobs

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment, rsync, cicd

I'm trying to do an automatic deployment to the host server from GitHub, but I got the following errors:

[image: Error logs]

Look my workflow file content:

```yaml
name: Prosperium Production CI  
   on:  
       push:  
           branches:  
               - main  
   jobs:  
       build:  
           runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
           steps:  
               - name: Check-out do repositório  
                 uses: actions/checkout@v1  
               - name: Deploy Ambiente de Produção  
                 uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@main  
                 env:  
                   SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{secrets.SERVER_SSH_KEY}}  
                   ARGS: "-rltgoDzvO --delete"  
                   SOURCE: "/"    
                   REMOTE_HOST: ${{secrets.REMOTE_HOST}}  
                   REMOTE_USER: ${{secrets.REMOTE_USER}}  
                   REMOTE_PORT: ${{secrets.REMOTE_PORT}}  
                   TARGET: ${{secrets.REMOTE_TARGET}}
```

I've already tried changing `REMOTE_PATH` and `SOURCE`, but there's no way!

Comment: Please include your workflow as text. Also, looks like it about `github-actions` but you added `gitlab-ci-runner` tag as well. Please remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I removed the wrong tag and pasted the workflow as text. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you! Please add the error as text also. From the error screenshot, it looks like some missing file or directory causing this. Apparently, not related to the GHA workflow or that action itself. You need to verify that.